# In app purchases for android with in native video player

Tags: android, video, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to create an V.O.D App for android that will be able to use in app purchases (the native android or any other platform like MoVend/etc...) within the native video player.
I'm trying to be able to let the user play a movie and after a couple of minutes it will load the paying option that only after paying it will continue playing the video.

Any suggestions?

Thanks